# How do I install openjdk-16-jdk for my nodejs app using my dockerfile?

Tags: java, node.js, docker

I have a Dockerfile with the following configuration:

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apt-get update && apt search openjdk && apt-get install -y default-jre  && npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 25565
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

the only available packages for jdk are version 11.
what do I need to add to get openjdk-16-jdk installed for this nodejs app.

Context: This app spawns a 1.17 version minecraft server that requires openjdk version 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single FROM per generated image. As you are trying to use node as a base image and install java to it, You can do the following:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
```

You can choose the version you need:

```
apt install openjdk-16-jre
```

Comment: I get Unable to locate package openjdk-16-jre